# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::createRow() in ZF2

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

In ZF1, there was a function `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::createRow()` to create a new blank row. This new row could then be manipulated and stored in the table. The `rowID` was set automatically with autoincrement and values were populated with default values from the DB schema.

How can I do this in **ZF2**? Is there a replacement for `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::createRow()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging in ZF2 source code I found out how to get prototype back. This is highly inspired by `Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway::executeSelect()` and `Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet`. I use this method in my AbstractMapper for convenience. As you may have guessed this will only work with `ResultSet` (as opposed to `HydratingResultSet`). But I guess this is your case also, otherwise you would not need such a method.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Mapper;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AbstractMapper
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway 
     */
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    /**
     * Create and returns a new row which is not yet saved in database
     * @return AbstractModel
     */
    public function createRow()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->getResultSetPrototype();
        $newRow = clone $resultSet->getArrayObjectPrototype();

        return $newRow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TableGateway:

```
$table= new TableGateway('users', $adapter);
$rowset = $table->insert(array('username' => 'bob'));
```

Comment: This will create a record in database, which may not be the desired effect. We may need a "temporary" object.